# Added value of libevent

Tags: c++, c, gcc, epoll, libevent

If we want mainly an `epoll` based loop over file-descriptors, what else features does the `libevent` offer (not interested in `http` or `dns` stuff)??

I know it's quite a big project, but it looks quite simple to me to write an `epoll` wrapper API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`epoll` is only available on Linux; `libevent` contains some abstractions such that it'll use other similar APIs on other operating systems (for instance: `kqueue` on OpenBSD).

Comment: So it can be said that libevent is only a "big loop (epoll, IOCP...)" implementation but portable?

Comment: Yes, but it has other benefits (such as the http/dns stuff you don't need).

Answer (score 0):

The added value that you can find in libevent is the portability. Your same code will run file on Windows or with different API than just epoll().

Plus you don't have to reinvent the wheel :)